# Modify data for view

Tags: php

I need to understand what is the best pattern for modifying data(be it collection of objects or array) which is passed from controller to view file.

Say I have 10 records of User entity. So array looks like this:

```
array(
 0 => object User(),
 1 => object User(),
 2 => object User(),
 3 => object User(),
 etc...
);
```

And the view needs this data to look like this:

```
array(
 0 => array(
   0 => object User(),
   1 => object User(),
 ),
 1 => array(
   0 => object User(),
   1 => object User(),
 ),
 etc...
)
```

So that users are grouped by two in sub-array.

Mind that this is just an example. I need to be able to modify data returned from query before i pass it to view. What is the best pattern for this?

UPDATE

May be i wasn't clear enough before. I'm asking about the PATTERN - in terms of OOP. What class pattern would contain this concrete function to format data for view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$a = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$b = array();
$c = count($a)/2;
for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
    if($c%2 == 0) $b[$i] = array($a[$i*2], $a[$i*2+1]);
    else if($c%2 != 0 && $i == floor($c)) $b[$i] = array($a[$i*2]);
    else $b[$i] = array($a[$i*2], $a[$i*2+1]);
}
var_dump($b);
```

Comment: Again, i'm asking about the PATTERN - in terms of OOP. What class pattern would contain this concrete function?